# How I can flatten a count table in postgresql that contains only 2 columns with crosstab?

Tags: postgresql, pivot

In my database I have the following table:

```
Mytable
id SERIAL,
category VARCHAR,
value VARCHAR
```

And I execute the following query:

```
select category, COUNT(*) from mytable group by category
```

What I want is to generate a single row value containing the following:

```
category1 | category2 |  category3
1234      | 3456      |  12345
```

The table return the following results:

```
 category   | Value
`category1` | 1234
`category2` | 3456
`category3` | 12345
```

Do you have any idea how to do this?
I have looked the crosstab function but required an extra column named `row_name` that in my cases does not exist. Also using a second query seems like a waste to me.

The

Comment: This page has a handy table about what dbs support `filter` functionality: [filter — Selective Aggregates](https://modern-sql.com/feature/filter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select count(*) filter (where category = 'category1') as category1,
       count(*) filter (where category = 'category2') as category2,
       count(*) filter (where category = 'category3') as category3
from the_table;
```